# How to check a Switch GE port's link-type?

Tags: router, networking

How to check a Quidway Switch GE port's link-type?
I have a `S5700` switch, and I want to check its GE0/0/1 port's link-type whether is access.

I have tried use bellow command:

```
[Huawei]display interface GigabitEthernet 0/0/1
GigabitEthernet0/0/1 current state : UP
Line protocol current state : UP
Description:
Switch Port, PVID :    1, TPID : 8100(Hex), The Maximum Frame Length is 9216
IP Sending Frames' Format is PKTFMT_ETHNT_2, Hardware address is 4c1f-cc09-0f2a
Last physical up time   : 2018-10-25 12:05:19 UTC-08:00
Last physical down time : 2018-10-25 12:04:27 UTC-08:00
Current system time: 2018-10-25 15:16:46-08:00
Hardware address is 4c1f-cc09-0f2a
    Last 300 seconds input rate 0 bytes/sec, 0 packets/sec
    Last 300 seconds output rate 0 bytes/sec, 0 packets/sec
    Input: 60 bytes, 1 packets
    Output: 625345 bytes, 5255 packets
    Input:
      Unicast: 0 packets, Multicast: 0 packets
      Broadcast: 1 packets
    Output:
      Unicast: 0 packets, Multicast: 5255 packets
      Broadcast: 0 packets
    Input bandwidth utilization  :    0%
    Output bandwidth utilization :    0%
```

and this method:

```
[Huawei]interface GigabitEthernet 0/0/1
[Huawei-GigabitEthernet0/0/1]display this
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
#
return
```

But I did not found the `link-type`.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so you should accept the answer so that it does not keep popping up. Alternatively you can add your own answer and accept that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in the Port, your second method is right.

if you did not configure the port to access or trunk, there will not shows it.

if you configured there will shows link this:

```
[Huawei-GigabitEthernet0/0/1]display this
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 port link-type access
#
return
```